# What is the --domainname option used for in Docker?

Tags: docker

I've been searching the web back and forth and just couldn't find something informative enough about the `--domainname` in `docker run`

What is the meaning of it? What effect does it have?

I'm trying to run this `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  server:
    domainname: myexample.com
    hostname: myserver
    image: "net-utils:0.3"
    command: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
  client:
    domainname: myexample.com
    hostname: myclient
    image: "net-utils:0.3"
    command: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

And now from within the container:

```
root@myclient:/# ping myserver.myexample.com
ping: myserver.myexample.com: No address associated with hostname
root@myclient:/# ping server.myexample.com
ping: server.myexample.com: No address associated with hostname
```

So what is the use of it?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/962658/how-to-define-domainname-in-a-docker-run-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--domainname` option has nothing to do with DNS or hostnames. From the `docker run` man page:

```
       --domainname=""
          Container NIS domain name

       Sets the container's NIS domain name (see also setdomainname(2)) that is
          available inside the container.
```

It sets the NIS domainname, which is only relevant if you're using [NIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service), which these days isn't all that likely.